# Why the environment variable is unset after using setenv( )

Tags: c, linux

I wrote a C program in Linux to set the values of environment variables using `setenv`, but after execution, when I run `set` or `export`, the environment variable itself seems to be unset. Why?

Here is the code snippet:

```
int main()
{
  char *mallocPtr, *callocPtr, *reallocPtr, *memalignPtr, *vallocPtr;
  struct sigaction sa;

  sa.sa_handler=SIGSEGV_handler;
  sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);

  if(setenv("ENV1", "3", 1) == 0)
         printf("ENV1 set to 3\n");
  else
         fprintf(stderr, "setenv failed on ENV1");
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The environment variables are set within the context of your program.

When your program exits, you're back in the context from where your program was started.

Comment: "[..]each process has a separate copy of the environment. As a result, you can't change the value of an environment variable in another process, such as the shell." from [here](http://www.steve.org.uk/Reference/Unix/faq_2.html#SEC8).

Comment: @Didier: But if the option "1" last argument of setenv is set, then i am expecting it to overwrite the already existing ones right? But it is not overwriting.

Comment: The man page for `getenv(), setenv()`, etc. says: `These functions set, unset and fetch environment variables from the host
     environment list.`

Comment: @Rudy: That's it..so it means it should set in my shell (or at least overwrite), right?

Comment: @kingsmasher1: you need to read the man page more carefully: `The setenv() function inserts or resets the environment variable name in the current environment list.  If the variable name does not exist in the list, it
     is inserted with the given value.  If the variable does exist, the argument overwrite is tested; if overwrite is zero, the variable is not reset, otherwise
     it is reset to the given value.` -- the overwrite parameter just controls whether you overwrite your existing environment variable setting - it has nothing to do with exporting the environment variable.

Comment: It overwrites the existing ones in the current process - try calling getenv in your program to see the change - but the current process is not the shell

Comment: @Paul R: `it has nothing to do with exporting the environment variable` so it means since it is not exported, it won't be seen, also if i set reset to "1" then the program does not use the existing value, but the value specified in setenv, right?

Comment: I can see that getenv done within same program gets the value set using setenv, but another shared library cannot. It extracts the one exported in the shell.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: that is what one could read into it, but that is not what happens.

Comment: i downvoted this answer. there are no details at all. the answer by zwol is much better.

Answer (score 7):

The C library treats environment variables as global settings you can read with `getenv` and adjust with `setenv`/`putenv`, and that inherit across calls to the `exec` family, but that is a convenient fiction.  As far as the kernel is concerned, the environment variables are **a second set of arguments to `main`**.  This becomes clear if you look at the actual system call, [`execve`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve), underlying the `exec` family.  This is its C prototype:

```
int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See that third argument?  That's the *only* way for process A to set process B's environment variables.<sup>1</sup>  Therefore, the only *time* process A can set process B's environment variables is when process A *starts* process B, via `fork` and `execve`.

Your program is started *by* the shell, so the shell got to set its copy of the environment variables, but there is no way for it to push a change back to the shell -- just as there is no way for a C function to change the values of its arguments in its caller.

<sup>1</sup> Do not bring up `ptrace`.

Comment: best answer, explains everything

Answer (score 1):

Actually every process has its own `envp` char array. The `main` function has the following signature:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
```

Usually, the `envp` of the parent inherit to the child, down the parent-child hierarchy. It is by no means communicated upwards in the parent-child hierarchy.

Comment: `main` with three arguments is definitely non-standard C. Some implementation may support it, but you shouldn't rely on it.